# Invoke an Alexa Skill task from a web service

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am having a use case where we need to invoke a Alexa Skill directive/task from a webservice. We have all data like access token, deviceId, CustomerId, etc., in the caller webservice. I need to see whether there is a way we can invoke a custom skill from backend.

Thanks in Advance.